# Passing array as Parameter to SQL 2005 stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

How to pass array as parameter to a Store Procedure in SQL Server 2005, i this is not possible SQL server 2000, so we pass comma separated values in past.

any help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

For a number of different ways to do this, please see:

[Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response, seems like we are unable to pass array directly but can achieve desired goal through many alternatives mention in above link

Answer (score 0):

This is still the case with Sql Server 2005.

You make use of the XML type

[XML Support in Microsoft SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117(SQL.90).aspx)

Here is an example of how to split a string into rows using the XML data type

```
DECLARE @textXML XML
DECLARE @data NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @delimiter NVARCHAR(5)

SELECT  @data = 'A,B,C',
        @delimiter = ','

SELECT    @textXML = CAST('<d>' + REPLACE(@data, @delimiter, '</d><d>') + '</d>' AS XML)
SELECT  T.split.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') AS data
FROM    @textXML.nodes('/d') T(split)
```

Comment: Problem with using XML is that the markup eats the characters you can submit, because the markup is characters as well :/

Comment: Hye, how are you, havent seen you in some time. Yes that is unfortunately true X-(

Comment: I'm doing my best to keep ahead of you, but it's hard work =)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a CSV, you could send an XML and then parse it in the procedure. For an example, look at [Passing lists to SQL Server 2005 with XML Parameters](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/02/16/passing-lists-to-sql-server-2005-with-xml-parameters.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

See [Passing an array or DataTable into a stored procedure](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/PassingArraysIntoSPs.aspx?msg=1095667) for a method of passing arrays as image / varbinary objects and parsing them in the SP which is possible in SQL 2000 as well.