# Using sets as inparameters to function/sproc in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, view

Is it possible to use a set, like (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) for example, as inparameter to a Sproc, function or view in SQL Server 2008?

What should I use of Sproc, function or View for this pice of SLQ?

```
WITH Scores AS(
    SELECT
        ItemId, SUM(Score) AS Score

    FROM [Presenta].[presenta].[LpivScores]

    WHERE
        // HERE I want (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) to be the inparameter, like @inParam
        ListPropertyItemId IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

    GROUP BY
        ItemId
)

-- I want this to be returned
SELECT
    i.Id,
    s.Score
FROM
    Scores s,
    Items i
WHERE
    s.ItemId = i.Id
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see:

- [T-SQL stored procedure that accepts multiple Id values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249/t-sql-stored-procedure-that-accepts-multiple-id-values)
- [Passing array as Parameter to SQL 2005 stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922191/passing-array-as-parameter-to-sql-2005-stored-procedure)

In SQL Server 2008, you can use [table valued parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to take a look at [Table Valued Parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Here a couple of more techniques to look at apart table valued parameters.

You can go ahead with comma separated values but you would need to create a function to split those comma separated values.
http://vyaskn.tripod.com/passing_arrays_to_stored_procedures.htm

Other way is to use XML Parameters.
http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/02/16/passing-lists-to-sql-server-2005-with-xml-parameters.aspx